# UIScrollView is not working properly when the parent view is used as a child ViewController of a TabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have an UIScrollView that is working properly in an UIViewController.

[image: Working]

But,when I try to use the UIViewController as a child view controller of an UITabBarController, the screen is locked.
It seems that the `contentSize` is not working.

[image: contentSize is much smaller than before.]

Comment: remove option "under bottom bars" in ViewController of Storyboard

Comment: That does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the TabBarController, setting the `contentSize` property in `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` override function worked.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print(self.m_scrollView.contentSize);
        self.m_scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: m_height)
    }
```

I tried to print the `contentSize` property in `viewDidLoad` and noticed that it was not changed as the value set in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.